# GML TimePeriod mapping in MapForce

Tags: convert, sql-server, fme-form, gml

I made a SQLServer database structure based on an XSD schema I got. In that schema two fields have gml:TimePeriodType. In database I put two columns for each field of this type (begin and end) and the datatype is datetime. I use FME to translate database into GML, and then MapForce to map that GML to XSD schema.

I supposed that I can map begin and end column to some attributes of TimePeriod columns in my XSD schema. But (guess), I cannot do it. Can some help me what I need to do and where I am wrong?

FME is translating this columns into string (e.g. 20140522000000.000), which is weird to me (I think I need 2014-05-22T00:00:00 format).

What I am missing?

Sorry if question is stupid, but I am new to all of this, and I need pointers for going forward.

Answer (score 1):

On the FME side of things you need to add a DateFormatter transformer into your workspace. Use it to convert the source date (20140522000000.000) to ISO DateTime (2014-05-22T00:00:00)

[image]

Also make sure the GML Writer is set to use a DateTime for the output, and not a char field:

[image]

Comment: My FME is quite different, but I will try. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you are using FME Workbench (and not just the FME Quick Translator)